# Detect if certain db table rows are set?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I want to create a script which detects if certain rows in a mysql table no longer are empty.

I guess i need to run a php script every 5th second which checks certail table rows. If any of them are empty it should continue updating. If not it should redirect to another php page which shows the updated/filled tables.

Any ideas on how to do this?

It is kind of like the game "who wants to be a millionaire" where x persons gets the same question which they need to answer. Answering them will store their answers in certain table rows. When these rows are not empty the main page needs to show all answers and how long time they have spent answering them.

I just need the updste each 5th second script which returns "true" or "false" (if any of the rows are empty).

Cheers,

Mads

Comment: did you already try something ?

Answer (score 0):

Polling table every 5 seconds sounds very wrong.

You should rethink you workflow on how you react to external events.

If you can afford changing your database to PostgreSQL, it offers good solution for this problem. Namely, you create trigger on table of interest, and inside that trigger use `NOTIFY`.

Another connection that wants to react to table changes, will use `LISTEN` to register for notifications and then simply go to sleep using `select()` on connection handle. Then, once trigger has fired, this connection will immediately receive this event and can react on it right away.

This approach allows to use exactly 0 CPU time on both server and client and yet react on changes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this :

Set a JavaScript timer when the player answers the question (displaying a 'waiting for other players to answer' message for example) and triggering an asynchronous query to a php script (let's say waiting.php) every 5 seconds. If waiting.php returns 0, nothing happens. In waiting.php returns 1, player is redirected on the page witch will display all the answers and times

In waiting.php, write something like that :

```
echo (current(mysql_fetch_row(mysqli_query('SELECT count(*) from responses WHERE questionId = '.$_GET['QuestionId'].' AND answer_field IS NULL'))) > 0 ? '0' : '1');
```